# I am getting 400 BAD REQUEST in tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I am using tastypie. When I want to post data to my server I am getting:

My curl command is:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{{"shop" : "/api/shop/1/","transactions" : [{"item" : "/api/item/53/","note" : "Normal"}]}' 'http://localhost:5000/api/order/'
```

The response is:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 BAD REQUEST
Date: Mon, 21 Jul 2014 13:41:52 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.5
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,Content-Type,Accept
Content-Language: tr
Vary: Accept-Language, Cookie
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf
```

Table create syntaxes:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_order` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `table` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `shop_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `shop_id_refs_id_d3748fa9` (`shop_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `shop_id_refs_id_d3748fa9` FOREIGN KEY (`shop_id`) REFERENCES `t_shop` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=231 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `t_transaction` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `note` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `closed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `item_id_refs_id_348f1ee9` (`item_id`),
  KEY `order_id_refs_id_d9a0bcc6` (`order_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `item_id_refs_id_348f1ee9` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `t_item` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=71 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
STATUSES = (
    (0, 'OPEN'),
    (1, 'CLOSED'),
    (2, 'CANCELLED'),
)
table = CharField(max_length=100)
shop = ForeignKey(Shop)
date_modified = DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
date_created = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
status = IntegerField(choices=STATUSES)
class Meta:
        db_table = 't_order'

class Transaction(models.Model):
order = ForeignKey('Order')
note = CharField(max_length=500)
item = ForeignKey(Item)
closed = BooleanField(default=False)
date_modified = DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Meta:
        db_table = 't_transaction'
```

What is the problem?

Comment: How do you run the django code (uwsgi?), and does it produce some logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid. Please validate your curl data [here](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/). The 400 (bad request) status should give you clue about that. To make sure you can create serializer which can handle that exception.

```
from tastypie.exceptions import BadRequest

class VerboseSerializer(Serializer):
    """
    Gives message when loading JSON fails.
    """
    # Tastypie>=0.9.6,<=0.11.0
    def from_json(self, content):
        """
        Override method of `Serializer.from_json`. Adds exception message when loading JSON fails.
        """
        try:
            return json.loads(content)
        except ValueError as e:
            raise BadRequest(u"Incorrect JSON format: Reason: \"{}\" (See www.json.org for more info.)".format(e.message))

class MyResource(BaseModelResource):
    class Meta:
        serializer = VerboseSerializer(formats=['json'])
```